# In Haskell, Can Kinds Be Anything Other Than a Sequence of Stars?

Tags: haskell

Please forgive me if this question is dumb.

While reading about Haskell kinds, I notice a theme:

```
*
* -> *
* -> * -> *
```

I get the impression that kinds in Haskell ultimately boil down to how many asterisks there are. You might say that the kind of a type is really just the number of types you need to apply to it before it becomes *. In other words, you could count all *'s but the last one, and define a type's kind by an integer. Say 0, 1, 2, etc.

Here's my question:

Is this a correct observation about Haskell's type system? Or does it allow something other than *'s to go where you typically see *'s? For example:

```
* -> a -> *
```

I imagine someone might want to do this to constrain type variables to have an instance of a type class, for example.

```
Functor a, Applicative b => * -> a -> b -> *
```

Is that a thing?

Comment: You can work with `DataKinds`, if you then define a `data Foo = Foo Nat` for example, you can define a type `type Bar = Foo 42`, and `Bar` has kind `Foo`.

Comment: Even restricting ourselves to the `*` kind (also known as `Type`) the kinds `* -> * -> *` and `(* -> *) -> *` wouldn't be the same.

Comment: `Nat` is for example a kind that allows to use natural numbers as kind.

Comment: as a common example of what @danidiaz mentions, [Monad Transformers](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers) are very widely used in "real world" Haskell, and such transformers, eg `MaybeT`, have kind `(* -> *) -> * -> *`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The most basic form of the kind language contains only `*` (or `Type` in more modern Haskell; I suspect we'll eventually move away from `*`) and `->`.

But there are more things you can build with that language than you can express by just "counting the number of `*`s". It's not just the number of `*` or `->` that matter, but how they are nested. For example `* -> * -> *` is the kind of things that take two type arguments to produce a type, but `(* -> *) -> *` is the kind of things that take a single argumemt to produce a type where that argument itself must be a thing that takes a type argument to produce a type. `data ThreeStars a b = Cons a b` makes a type constructor with kind `* -> * -> *`, while `data AlsoThreeStars f = AlsoCons (f Integer)` makes a type constructor with kind `(* -> *) -> *`.

There are several language extensions that add more features to the kind language.

`PolyKinds` adds kind *variables* that work exactly the same way type variables work. Now we can have kinds like `forall k. (* -> k) -> k`.

`ConstraintKinds` makes constraints (the stuff to the left of the `=>` in type signatures, like `Eq a`) become ordinary type-level entities in a new kind: `Constraint`. Rather than the stuff left of the `=>` being special purpose syntax fairly disconnected from the rest of the language, now what is acceptable there is anything with kind `Constraint`. Classes like `Eq` become type constructors with kind `* -> Constraint`; you apply it to a type like `Eq Bool` to produce a `Constraint`. The advantage is now we can use all of the language features for manipulating type-level entities to manipulate constraints (including `PolyKinds`!).

`DataKinds` adds the ability to create new user-defined kinds containing new type-level things, in exactly the same way that in vanilla Haskell we can create new user-defined types containing new term-level things. (**Exactly** the same way; the way `DataKinds` actually works is that it lets you use a `data` declaration as normal and then you can use the resulting type constructor at either the type or the kind level)

There are also kinds used for unboxed/unlifted types, which must not be ever mixed with "normal" Haskell types because they have a different memory layout; they can't contain thunks to implement lazy evaluation, so the runtime has to know never to try to "enter" them as a code pointer, or look for additional header bits, etc. They need to be kept separate at the kind level so that ordinary type variables of kind `*` can't be instantiated with these unlifted/unboxed types (which would allow you to pass these types that need special handling to generic code that doesn't know to provide the special handling). I'm vaguely aware of this stuff but have never actually had to use it, so I won't add any more so I don't get anything wrong. (Anyone who knows what they're talking about enough to write a brief summary paragraph here, please feel free to edit the answer)

There are probably some others I'm forgetting. But certainly the kind language is richer than the OP is imagining just with the basic Haskell features, and there is much more to it once you turn on a few (quite widely used) extensions.

Comment: Another source of  kinds are the kinds of types whose values might be "unlifted" or "unboxed". The kind `*` a.k.a. `Type` is the kind of types like `Int` whose values are "lifted", that is, that can be pending computations (thunks) or even `undefined`. But Haskell also has types like `Int#` which are actual "machine ints" that can't be thunks. And each possible in-memory representation has its own kind. This aspect of GHC is still evolving. https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/exts/primitives.html#unboxed-type-kinds

Comment: @danidiaz Yeah, I vaguely follow the developments in that area as they appear in GHC release notes. But I've never really had to use unlifted/unboxed things, so I don't have a good grasp of how it all fits together; I just know where to start reading when I do need to get a better grasp.

Comment: @Ben I have a question about this part: "PolyKinds adds kind variables that work exactly the same way type variables work. Now we can have kinds like ```forall k. (* -> k) -> k```." Forall k is universal k. And * is not constrained, although at least 1 person has written that * is not a wildcard either. What is the difference between * and forall k?

Comment: @JamesStrieter `k` is a variable,  you can instantiate it to any kind you like: `*`, or `* -> *`, or `(* -> *) -> *`, etc. `*` is one specific concrete kind. It doesn't stand as a placeholder to be instantiated by something else, it **is** the most basic kind; it is also called `Type`, now, but it always acted like a basic name like `Type`, not like a wildcard or operator as the `*` symbol might suggest.

Comment: That makes sense. I can see why the community might move away from the * notation in the future. Personally I think it would be more readable to use the number 0 to denote the most basic kind, because it is 0-arity.

Comment: @JamesStrieter You could, although "having zero arity" isn't a very distinctive feature. Every member of the kind `Bool` is also zero arity (`True` and `False`, lifted to type-level with the `DataKinds` extension). Any enum-like type will similarly contain only zero-arity things. `Type` is a **much** better name, since that describes what it means and what is unique about it: every type-level thing whose kind is `Type` can be used as the type of things at the term level, while no type-level thing with a different kind can be used that way.